# Page load strategy for Chrome driver (Updated till Selenium v3.12.0)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pageloadstrategy

I'm using Chrome browser for testing WebApp.

Sometimes pages loaded after very long time. I needed to stop downloading or limit their download time.

In FireFox I know about `PAGE_LOAD_STRATEGY = "eager"`.

Is there something similar for chrome?

P.S.: `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout()` works, but after that any treatment to Webdriver throws `TimeOutException`.
I need to get the current url of the page after stopping its boot.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**ChromeDriver 77.0** (which supports Chrome version 77) now supports **`eager`** as *pageLoadStrategy*.

> Resolved issue 1902: Support eager page load strategy [Pri-2]

---

From the Webdriver specs:

> *For commands that cause a new document to load, the point at which the command returns is determined by the **session’s page loading strategy**.*

When `Page Loading` takes too much time and you need to stop downloading additional subresources (images, css, js etc) you can change the  **`pageLoadStrategy`** through the `webdriver`.

As of this writing, **`pageLoadStrategy`** supports the following values :

1. **`normal`**

   This stategy causes Selenium to wait for the full page loading (html content and subresources downloaded and parsed).
2. **`eager`**

   This stategy causes Selenium to wait for the DOMContentLoaded event (html content downloaded and parsed only).
3. **`none`**

   This strategy causes Selenium to return immediately after the initial page content is fully received (html content downloaded).

By default, when `Selenium` loads a page, it follows the **`normal`** **`pageLoadStrategy`**.

---

Here is the code block to configure [**`pageLoadStrategy()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/PageLoadStrategy.html) through both an instance of **DesiredCapabilities** Class and **ChromeOptions** Class as follows : :

- Using **DesiredCapabilities** Class :

  ```
  package demo; //replace by your own package name

  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

  public class A_Chrome_DCap_Options {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          DesiredCapabilities dcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
          dcap.setCapability("pageLoadStrategy", "normal");
          ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
          opt.merge(dcap);
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
          driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Using **ChromeOptions** Class :

  ```
  package demo; //replace by your own package name

  import org.openqa.selenium.PageLoadStrategy;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;


  public class A_Chrome_Options_test {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
          opt.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
          driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```

> **Note** : `pageLoadStrategy` values **`normal`**, **`eager`** and **`none`** is a requirement as per [**WebDriver W3C Editor's Draft**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#navigation) but `pageLoadStrategy` value as **`eager`** is still a *WIP (Work In Progress)* within **ChromeDriver** implementation. You can find a detailed discussion in [“Eager” Page Load Strategy workaround for Chromedriver Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087832/eager-page-load-strategy-workaround-for-chromedriver-selenium-in-python)

---

References:

- [WebDriver navigation](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#h-navigation)
- [WebDriver page load strategies](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-table-of-page-load-strategies)
- [WhatWG Document readyStateChange / readiness](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-readystate-dev)

Comment: Yes! It helps me. But why.....?
How it works? 
Why we must set pageLoadStrategy = none?
Why pageLoadStrategy = eager not works?

Comment: @DebanjanB Your answer doesn't explain how change in `pageLoadStrategy` affects the behavior, so a follow-up question is more than expected, and not answering it is just plain rude. Thanks

Comment: @PanamaBoy Chrome does not support the eager page load strategy.

Comment: Can you provide your code in Python? I use Python and I don't know how to write it in Python, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For Selenium 4 and Python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

For more details can be found here https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/shared/#none

Answer (score 0):

In C#, since PageLoadStrategy.Eager doesn't seem to work for Chrome, I just wrote it myself with a WebDriverWait. Set the PageLoadStrategy to none and then doing this will basically override it:

```
new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))
    .Until(d =>
    {
      var result = ((IJavaScriptExecutor) d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState");
      return result.Equals("interactive") || result.Equals("complete");
    });
```

You just add in your chrome driver as a parameter and the TimeSpan is set to a max of 20 seconds in my case. So it will wait a max of 20 seconds for the page to be interactive or complete

Answer (score -2):

Try using explicit wait . Visit [this](http://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html) link. It might be helpful

Try this code as well:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String startURL = //a starting url;
String currentURL = null;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

foo(driver,startURL);

/* go to next page */
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='someID']")).isDisplayed()){
    String previousURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='someID']")).click();  
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    ExpectedCondition e = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
          public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return (d.getCurrentUrl() != previousURL);
          }
        };

    wait.until(e);
    currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    System.out.println(currentURL);
}
```

I hope your problem will be resolved using above code