# How to immediately invoke driver.quit() in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageloadstrategy

Whenever I call `driver.quit()` it waits for the website to first complete loading then it closes the browser, is there any way I can force close the browser immediately?

Comment: there's pageloadstrategy, but setting that will have other consequences... why would you go to a URL and then quit?

Comment: @pcalkins incase I have to abort the entire process in between, I mean we humans do it all the time I don't see why selenium can't do it too ;P

Comment: Sample code? My first guess is that the command to open the website finishes when the page is loaded. So the quit() simply needs to wait on the .get() to finish

Comment: @TacoVerhagen yea you're right just a simple .get() and an async .quit() in another function, actually I'm forking selenium from another process so the entire code would be a little difficult but you have the right idea

Comment: it'll wait for pageready state to return from wire protocol unless pageloadstrategy is set to none.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke `get()` for an *`url`* using *Selenium* a lot many actions happens under the hood, including *HTTP requests received by geckodriver, packets sent to and from the remote protocol in Firefox, and responses sent back to your client*.

Once the basic mandatory requests/responses are successfully completed, based on the [***pageLoadStrategy***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script/44771628#44771628) the browser i.e. the client sends back the program control to [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to perform the next line of code.

Now [*`pageLoadStrategy`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322165/dont-wait-for-a-page-to-load-using-selenium-in-python/46339092#46339092) can be either of the following:

- [*normail*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734797/page-load-strategy-for-chrome-driver-updated-till-selenium-v3-12-0/43737358#43737358): This stategy causes Selenium to wait for the full page loading (html content and subresources downloaded and parsed).
- [*eager*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087832/eager-page-load-strategy-workaround-for-chromedriver-selenium-in-python/51097396#51097396): This stategy causes Selenium to wait for the DOMContentLoaded event (html content downloaded and parsed only).
- [*none*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128396/selenium-chromedriver-open-extremely-slower-than-open-a-website-in-chrome-browse/44129861#44129861): This strategy causes Selenium to return immediately after the initial page content is fully received (html content downloaded).

So once the program control is returned back to *Selenium* based on *pageLoadStrategy* which is somewhat timebound, then only `driver.quit()` can be performed.