# Does chrome chrome driver support PageLoadStrategy='eager' for Selenium?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape some stuff using Selenium/headless chrome. In some pages, the  driver will not move to the next step until the full page is loaded (even though the relevant elements are present).

I tried setting the pageLoadStrategy capability like so:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args" => [ "--headless" ]})
      caps['pageLoadStrategy']='eager'
self.driver||=Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :desired_capabilities =>  caps
```

I get the following error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: cannot parse capability: pageLoadStrategy
from unknown error: page load strategy unsupported
```

Is there a way to make this work with chrome?

According to this post, pageLoadStrategy is supported, but I can't get the 'eager' option to work.

[Page load strategy for Chrome driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734797/page-load-strategy-for-chrome-driver)

If not, are there more tried and true ways of doing this. I've been having a lot of trouble with Chrome (it also doesn't support unexpectedAlertBehaviour)

Comment: The eager strategy is not yet supported ([source](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/test/chromedriver/capabilities.cc?rcl=04235e62d2eae12e49b31ee74d8e6a448e3d8cc5&l=185)). Use `none` and wait for `document.readyState` to be `interactive`.

Comment: Thanks @FlorentB. Whats the best way to implement that wait (document.readyState  interactive) .  Also, looking at the source code I see that unexpectedAlerBehaviour is implemented. I tried this extensively like 3 weeks ago with no luck. Any thoughts on how to make that work?  I should prob post a new question with that.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome does not support PageLoadStrategy.EAGER. But you can try PageLoadStrategy.NONE. Sometimes you need to synchronize driver wait for some elemnts but possibility is less.

Answer (score 3):

**ChromeDriver 77.0** (which supports Chrome version 77) now supports **`eager`** as *pageLoadStrategy*.

> Resolved issue 1902: Support eager page load strategy [Pri-2]

[See release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.10/notes.txt)

Comment: So  I have ChromeDriver 77 but still getting this message `invalid argument: 'pageLoadStrategy=eager' not yet supported`

Answer (score 1):

For those who are waiting for the "eager" feature. You can check the "CheckSupport" function in the [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/capabilities.cc#834).

It seems it is still not supported even for now.

Answer (score 1):

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/page_load_strategy.cc?q=page_load_strategy&sq=package:chromium&dr=C

The corresponding page load strategy for EAGER is not yet supported by chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The eager strategy now seems to be supported by chrome since v66 ([source](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/test/chromedriver/capabilities.cc?l=202&rcl=e9d39029faf55d93a7e62c30ea9a244e48e0b132)).