# How to skip a specific pending API response from loading in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

There are possibilities of some 3rd party APIs that keep hanging sometimes, letting the actual tests to fail with the timeout error.

Is there some hack to specifically skip such pending API responses?

[image]

Comment: When do you want to skip? During initial page loading?

Comment: @DebanjanB yea on initial page load I want to skip this specific api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Selenium not wait till full page load, which has a slow script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script)

Comment: Can you give us more context about it? What does this API call do in your UI? If it's irrelevant, you can just "rescue" the exception, log it somewhere and go on. You could retry to call it (if triggered by the UI). Now, if the request to this API is mandatory to make your UI work, then I would find a logic to identify that it has hung and retry the whole test for a number of times (i.e. 3 times).

Comment: @DebanjanB Do we have pageLoadStrategy for Chrome? if so, can you post the answer

Comment: Check this QA - [**Page load strategy for Chrome driver**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734797/page-load-strategy-for-chrome-driver/43737358#43737358) Upvote both the Answers if they were useful to you.

Comment: @Tom I am already using retry in my tests, the API call in my application is about google analytics that we cannot purge it from the application and I believe the GA server is slow today that makes my tests to fail. Hope you know we cannot rescue the API responses by default since Selenium wait for the entire page to load along with the API responses.

Comment: @DebanjanB It looks like a possible fix but do you know how to implement it in Ruby?

Comment: well, you have to use the `DesiredCapabilities` and pass it while you initiate the WebBrowser.

Comment: yea but the syntax seems different for Ruby; can you please me on that

Comment: @DebanjanB setting the pageLoadStrategy to 'eager' throws error for me; however, normal and none works but it's of no use in my scenario
```
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
  caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

Answer (score 0):

This option helped me:

```
$this->driver->manage()->timeouts()->pageLoadTimeout(1);
try {
    $this->driver->get($pageUrl);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
$this->pageHtml = $this->driver->getPageSource();
```