# Tests timeouts (Selenium+Jenkins+Grid)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

We've started getting random timeouts, but can not get reasons of that. The tests run on remote machines on amazon using selenium grid. Here is how it is going on:

- browser is opened,
- then a page is loading, but can not load fully within 120 seconds,
- then timeout exeption is thrown.

If I run the same tests localy then everything is ok.

The Error is ordinary timeout exception that is thrown if a page is not loaded completely during the period of time that is set in `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout()`. The problem is that a page of the site can not be loaded completely within that time. But, When period of time that is set in `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout()` is finished and, consequently, Selenium possession of a browser is finished, the page is loaded at once. The issue can not be reproduced manually on the same remote machines. We've tried different versions of Selenium standalone, Chromedriver, Selenium driver. Browser is Google Chrome 63. Would be happy to hear any suggestions about reasons.

Comment: Do your remote machines have access to hit your internal test site?

Comment: Can you update the question with the configuration of the binaries you are using along with the code trials, relevant HTML and error stack trace?

Comment: Code is simple: driver.get("URL");
I've updated discription of the question. Now it should be a bit more clear

Comment: When you run on local, you used same selenium grid as run on remote machine? or browser opened on local when run on local?

Comment: I do not use grid when run on local, I use just 1 machine for this

Answer (score 0):

When Selenium loads a webpage/url by default it follows a default configuration of *pageLoadStrategy* set to *normal*. To make Selenium not to wait for full page load we can configure the *pageLoadStrategy*. *pageLoadStrategy* supports 3 different values as follows:

- normal (full page load)
- eager (interactive)
- none

### Code Sample :

- *Java*

  ```
  capabilities.setCapability("pageLoadStrategy", "none");
  ```
- *Python*

  ```
  caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
  ```

> Here you can find the detailed discussions through [*Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734797/page-load-strategy-for-chrome-driver/43737358#43737358) and [*Python*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script/44771628#44771628) clients.